# How to exclude particular row id from query results?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of Member, in that I have three rows which has `member_id`s as `admins` , `admin` and `manager`. Now, I want to select all members from the table excluding these three `member_id`'s.

For this, I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Member` 
 WHERE Member.member_id NOT IN ( 
          SELECT member_id 
            FROM Member 
           WHERE Member.member_id = 'manager' 
             AND Member.member_id = 'admins' 
             AND Member.member_id = 'admin' 
    )
```

But still I can see those three rows selected in the result.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write query like below :

```
SELECT * FROM `Member` WHERE Member.member_id NOT IN ('admins' , 'admin','manager');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to make your query right. For better performance use Pratik's solution

```
 SELECT * FROM `Member` WHERE Member.member_id NOT IN ( SELECT member_id FROM Member WHERE Member.member_id = 'manager' OR Member.member_id = 'admins' OR Member.member_id = 'admin' )
```